# UnknownHostException trying to connect to Cloudant DB via Ektorp

Tags: java, couchdb, cloudant

It's not clicking how one is supposed to connect to a hosted Cloudant database using [Ektorp](http://code.google.com/p/ektorp/).  I'm using Ektorp 1.1 in Eclipse via the new [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) Maven integration (which is pretty sweet).  I'm struggling to find good CouchDB/Cloudant/Ektorp documentation other than javadocs.

I'm trying to get the sample Ektorp API example from their [main page](http://code.google.com/p/ektorp/) to work:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new StdHttpClient.Builder()
                                    .host("localhost")
                                    .port(5984)
                                    .build();

CouchDbInstance dbInstance = new StdCouchDbInstance(httpClient);
CouchDbConnector db = new StdCouchDbConnector("mydatabase", dbInstance);

db.createDatabaseIfNotExists();
```

It doesn't matter what I use to build the httpClient with, I always get the UnknownHostException error below.  I've tried these URLs for the host: https/http://cloudant.com/db/_session and https/http://[username].cloudant.com

What about the port number?  Should the username and password be included in the StdHttpClient.Builder()?

Here's the full error - it's failing on the createDatabaseIfNotExists() call but I'm not confident the CouchDbConnector variable is correct.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.ektorp.DbAccessException: java.net.UnknownHostException: https://cloudant.com/db/_session
    at org.ektorp.util.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:19)
    at org.ektorp.http.StdHttpClient.executeRequest(StdHttpClient.java:104)
    at org.ektorp.http.StdHttpClient.get(StdHttpClient.java:42)
    at org.ektorp.http.RestTemplate.get(RestTemplate.java:21)
    at org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbInstance.getAllDatabases(StdCouchDbInstance.java:61)
    at org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector.createDatabaseIfNotExists(StdCouchDbConnector.java:256)
    at com.codegouge.examples.App.main(App.java:30)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: https://cloudant.com/db/_session
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:850)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1201)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1154)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1084)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1020)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:126)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    at org.ektorp.http.StdHttpClient.executeRequest(StdHttpClient.java:96)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Ektorp, but you'll definitely need to get your username/password in there.  I'd suggest creating the HttpClient with the following code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new StdHttpClient.Builder()
                                    .host("[username].cloudant.com")
                                    .port(443)
                                    .username("[username]")
                                    .password("[password]")
                                    .build();
```

I've changed the port to 443 (the default for HTTPS, which Cloudant listens on) and I've added a username and password.  I don't see any way to let Ektorp know that you want to use HTTPS, but with luck that'll be handled internally.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Removing "http/s" from host enabled me to connect via port 5984 and execute the createDatabaseIfNotExists() call successfully.  However, using port 443 threw a java.net.SocketException.  I have to imagine Ektorp can handle HTTPS.  I'll keep looking.  Cheers!

Comment: So I realize I need to include ".enableSSL(true)" and ".relaxedSSLSettings(true)" when building my HttpClient but I'm now getting an IllegalStateException.

Comment: @Ryan Well, progress at least. :) Yeah, those look like the right methods to call. The Ektorp site still points to the 1.0.2 javadoc, so I didn't notice them (the SSL support appears to be new in 1.1).  If you're able to update your question to include the exception stack trace that might be helpful.

Comment: Matt, you're right that ssl is new to 1.1. Let me do some more investigation before posting another stack trace.

Comment: @Ryan OK. By the way, I reported the stale javadoc link as an issue and they've already fixed it.

Comment: @Matt I switched to Ektorp 1.1.1 and everything works fine now.  Apparently, this release includes several SSL bug fixes.  I'll post an answer in case people don't read comments.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

So I was doing a couple things wrong.  Using SSL [requires additional parameters](http://www.ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d99e209).  Also, [Ektorp 1.1.1 includes SSL-related bug fixes](http://groups.google.com/group/ektorp-discuss/browse_thread/thread/83d7ed8900d3e046/d847ca01b8b72295?lnk=gst&q=ssl#d847ca01b8b72295) to 1.1.0.  So this is my final HttpClient constructor:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new StdHttpClient.Builder()
        .host("[username].cloudant.com")
        .port(443)
        .username("[username]")
        .password("[password]")
        .enableSSL(true)
        .relaxedSSLSettings(true)
        .build();
```

Also, be sure to update ektorp's dependency in pom.xml to look for version "1.1.1".  I have a blog post covering this exercise [here](http://codegouge.blogspot.com/2011/04/rocking-and-rolling-with-ektorp-and.html) if interested.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore, do you mind having a quick look at: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ektorp-discuss/wWtChJMx9zs/discussion

Comment: This is the working solution, and the answer above does not work for me, and I am nto sure why that answer is accepted. Thanks, Ryan!

Answer (score 1):

You also can use the URL to connect with Ektorp:

```
JSONObject serviceAttr = val.getJSONObject(0);
                        JSONObject credentials = serviceAttr.getJSONObject("credentials");
                        httpClient = new StdHttpClient.Builder()
                        .url(credentials.getString("url"))
                        .build();
```

That's is easy way to connect. I found a tutorial to connect using Ektorp 1.4.2:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hangman-app/index.html